# Read a JSON gist as a query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, query-string

I currently have a Javascript application that consists of three files:

```
index.html
app.js
input.json
```

The input.json file gets referenced several times by the app.js file, in order to render content into divs in the index.html file.

I want to make it so that loading my index.html at http://example.com/myapp can take an externall hosted JSON as the source for app.js to read, like myexample.com/myapp?myhost.com/files/input.json.

Can anybody advise me on how to get this working?

Comment: [start here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/5090771) to get query string in `app.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, you need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on myexample.com.

Assuming you are using jQuery. (Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) if you don't want to use jQuery for ajax requests)

```
$.get('http://myexample.com/myapp?myhost.com/files/input.json')
.done(function(data) {
    // use external 'data' here.
})
.fail(function() {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I a using jQuery. So I've got the idea here, but if myhost.com/files/input.json can be any URL, how do I refer to it as a variable? specifically

```$.get('http://myexample.com/myapp?<json_url>', function(data) {
    // use external 'data' here.
});```

I want to get any URL that's there. Then first check if it's a JSON and throw an error if not--OR, just throw the can't read error if trying to parse it as a JSON in the `// use external 'data' here.` part can't read it.

Comment: I edited my answer to show handling errors on $.get. You can apply extra checks in .done() if you need. For example checking if the 'data' object is valid. You can also use try/catch block to control exceptions.

Comment: I think the last piece here then is to get the url of the current page, and then pass it as a variable to $.get. Right?

Comment: If the data you are fetching is on the same domain with the current page, you don't need to pass the full URL. Just call $.get with /files/input.json. Also CORS is not needed in this case. If different, you don't need the URL of the current page, you can call $.get with http://www.otherdomain.com/files/data.json assuming the other domain has proper CORS setting.

Comment: Great, this answers everything for me. Thanks!